# using type alias such as using A = int(int)

Tags: c++, c++11

With type alias we could introduce new type alias for example

```
using A = int(*)(int);
```

is similar to

```
typedef int(*A)(int);
```

I find the following code is also legal for current C++ compiler

```
using A = int(int);
```

I was wondering what's the type of A and how to use it ( I did not find it useful myself)

Here's the code, it works in gcc 6.3 and clang 4.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
using namespace std;
using A = int(int);
using B = int(*)(int);

int main(){
    int status;
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl; //Error in clang 4.0
    cout<<sizeof(B)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(function<int(int)>)<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(A).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(B).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(function<int(int)>).name()<<endl;
    cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(A).name(), 0, 0, &status)<<endl;
    cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(B).name(), 0, 0, &status)<<endl;
    cout<<abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(function<int(int)>).name(), 0, 0, &status)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
4
16
FiiE
PFiiE
St8functionIFiiEE
int (int)
int (*)(int)
std::function<int (int)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is `int(int)` as stated.

It's a function type, not an object type, so you cannot declare an object of type `A` or appy `sizeof` to it (gcc gives you a warning about it). You however can use `A*` which is a normal function pointer type:

```
A* a = myfunc;
```

You can also use `A` to instantiate a template, e.g `std::function<A>`.

Answer (score 2):

`using A = int(int);` Introduces an alias for a function type. It's an incomplete type that has some good uses. To better illustrate it, let's choose a better name, such `ButtonFunction`:

1. Declare functions:

   ```
    ButtonFunction some_func;

    int main() {
      return some_func(0);
    }

    int some_func(int) { // *Definitions* must be with the prototype 
      return 0;
    }
   ```

Even member functions:

```
    class foo {
      ButtonFunction mem_fun;
    };

    int foo::mem_fun(int) { return 0; }
```

The declarations of the functions are now more than just a prototype, they exhibit the purpose that the function is supposed to have.

2. Create pointers to functions:

   ```
    ButtonFunction* f_ptr = &some_func;
   ```

Pointer to members included:

```
    ButtonFunction foo::* f_ptr = &foo::mem_fun;
```

This allows the pointer semantics be explicit rather than hidden behind an alias. It's good for data types and function types alike.

3. Use as the parameter to templates. Compare `std::function<ButtonFunction>` and `std::function<int(int)>`. Which one is clearer about the purpose of the functor?